# Python subprocess.Popen not outputting correctly

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to run a command via Python. I'd like to ssh to another host and perform a ps command:

`ssh -q <hostname> ps -o pid,%mem,command ax | grep ABC | sort -V -k 3`

When I run the above command via the command line, I get the expected output. When I run it via Python (v. 3.7), nothing outputs. My code:

```
command = ["ssh", "-q", "<hostname>", "ps", "-o", "pid,%mem,command", "ax", "|", "grep", "ABC", "|", "sort", "-V", "-k", "3"]

p = subprocess.Popen(command,stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,encoding="utf-8", bufsize=0)

out, err = p.communicate()
print(out)
```

The last print statement is printing just a new line. Any ideas?

Comment: You are running `ssh` with 14 parameters, including two vertical bars and "grep".  To perform multiple piped commands, you have to use `shell=True` - in which case you should pass a single string as the command, your list is just going to be joined together into a string.  Or, you could do three separate subprocesses, with the stdout from earlier ones specified as the stdin of the later ones.  (As for debugging this yourself: you should have printed out `err`, too - I'm pretty sure it would contain a good clue as to the problem.)

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for the comment! It worked. Also, I did print out `err` as well but it gave a blank output as well.